# Swift 3 Compiler Error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'Any?!'

Tags: swift, google-maps, swift3, google-places-api

so please bear with me if I upload wrong. I am having trouble with these two lines:

```
let lat = ((((dic["results"] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "geometry") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "location") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "lat") as AnyObject).object(0) as! Double
let lon = ((((dic["results"] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "geometry") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "location") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "lng") as AnyObject).object(0) as! Double
```

These two lines bring up an error saying:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'Any?!'

Not sure how to solve this...

Here is all the code from the view controller....

```
import UIKit

protocol LocateOnTheMap { 
    func locateWithLongitude(_ lon: Double, andLatitude lat: Double, andTitle title: String)
}

class SearchResultsController: UITableViewController {

    var searchResults: [String]!
    var delegate: LocateOnTheMap!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.searchResults = Array()
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.searchResults.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.searchResults[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }



    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                            didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        // 1
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        // 2
        let correctedAddress:String! = self.searchResults[indexPath.row].addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.symbols)
        let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(correctedAddress)&sensor=false")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            // 3
            do {
                if data != nil{
                    let dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary

                    let lat = ((((dic["results"] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "geometry") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "location") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "lat") as AnyObject).object(0) as! Double
                    let lon = ((((dic["results"] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "geometry") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "location") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "lng") as AnyObject).object(0) as! Double
                    // 4
                    self.delegate.locateWithLongitude(lon, andLatitude: lat, andTitle: self.searchResults[indexPath.row])
                }

            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        })
        // 5
        task.resume()
    }


    func reloadDataWithArray(_ array:[String]){
        self.searchResults = array
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Try replacing the `AnyObject` casts in your `let lon = ((((dic["results"]  ...` line with Dictionaries like this `[String:Any]`

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3 you should cast the intermediary JSON based objects to the right type before diving down the chain.

You could go like this :

```
let dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableLeaves) as! [String:Any]
```

and then:

```
let lon = (((dic["results"] as! [String:Any])["geometry"] as! [String:Any]).["location"] as! [String:Any])["lng"] as! Double
```

Comment: @LBIMBA: did this help you ?